# How to make graph responsive?

Tags: css

I made graph in CSS and I made it to run animation when scroll down. Everything's works fine but main problem is this is not responsive. I want to write content on left and bottom border so its look like x and y axis.

following is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>CSS3 Graph Animation</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    backgr ound:  url(back.jpg) top left repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 12px normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    color:#fff;
}

* {margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none;}

img {border: none;}

a { 
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#00c6ff;
}

h1 {
    font: 4em normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;  margin: 0;
    text-align:center;
    color:#bbb;
}

h1 small{
    font: 0.2em normal  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing: 0.2em; line-height: 5em;
    display: block;
}

h2 {
    font: 2em normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {

background:  url(back.jpg) top left repeat;

    width:960px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 30px;
    padding-top:450px;
    position:relative;
}

/* GRAPH */

.line, .line1, .line2, .li ne3 {
    background:#2187e7; 
    width:0px;
    height:1px;
}

.running .line {
    -moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 -2em;
    -moz-animation:move 1s linear forwards;

    -webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 -2em;
    -webkit-animation:move 1s linear forwards;
}

.running .line1 {
    -moz-transform:rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 14em 30em;
    -moz-animation:move1 1s 1s linear forwards;

    -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 14em 30em;
    -webkit-animation:move1 1s 1s linear forwards;
}
.running .line2 {
    -moz-transform:rotate(-65deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 20em -22em;
    -moz-animation:move2 1s 2s linear forwards;

    -webkit-transform:rotate(-65deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20em -22em;
    -webkit-animation:move2 1s 2s linear forwards;
}


.running .ball,.running  .ball1,.running  .ball2,.running  .ball3,.running  .ball4 {
    background-color:#2187e7; 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff); 

    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:50px;

    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;

    -moz-transform:scale(0);
    -moz-animation:point 0.1s linear forwards;

    -webkit-transform:scale(0);
    -webkit-animation:point 0.1s linear forwards;
}

.running .pulse,.running .pulse1,.running  .pulse2,.running  .pulse3,.running  .pulse4 {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    border-radius:30px;
    border: 1px solid #00c6ff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #00c6ff;
    position:absolute;


    -moz-transform:scale(0);
    -moz-animation:pulse 1s ease-out;

    -webkit-transform:scale(0);
    -webkit-animation:pulse 1s ease-out;
}

/* TOOLTIP */

.ball a, .ball1 a, .ball2 a, .ball3 a, .ball4 a {
    float:left;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}

.ball a small, .ball1 a small, .ball2 a small, .ball3 a small, .ball4 a small { 
    background:#000; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:70px; 
    padding:5px; 
    border-left:1px solid #111; border-top:1px solid #111; border-right:1px solid #333; border-bottom:1px solid #333; 
    border-radius:3px; 
    display:none; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-size:0.8em; 
    text-indent:0;
}

.ball a:hover small, .ball1 a:hover small, .ball2 a:hover small, .ball3 a:hover small, .ball4 a:hover small { 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:50%; 
    margin:-40px; 
    z-index:9999; 

    -moz-animation:tooltip .25s linear;  

    -webkit-animation:tooltip .25s linear; 
} 

/* COORDINATE POINTS */

.ball  { top:445px; left:0; }
.ball1 { top:411px; left:196px; }
.ball2 { top:511px; left:372px; }
.ball3 { top:151px; left:544px; }

.pulse  { top:443px; left:-2px; }
.pulse1 { top:409px; left:194px; }
.pulse2 { top:509px; left:370px; }
.pulse3 { top:149px; left:542px; }


/* CONTROL LAYER DELAY */

#layerBall, #layerPulse   { -moz-animation-delay:0s; -webkit-animation-delay:0s; }
#layerBall1, #layerPulse1 { -moz-animation-delay:0.9s; -webkit-animation-delay:0.9s; }
#layerBall2, #layerPulse2 { -moz-animation-delay:1.9s; -webkit-animation-delay:1.9s; }
#layerBall3, #layerPulse3 { -moz-animation-delay:2.9s; -webkit-animation-delay:2.9s; }


/* ANIMATION */

@-moz-keyframes move {
    0%   { width:0px;}
    100% { width:200px; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.5); }
}
@-moz-keyframes move1 {
    0%   { width:0px;}
    100% { width:200px; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.5);}
}
@-moz-keyframes move2 {
    0%   { width:0px;}
    100% { width:400px; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.5);}
}
@-moz-keyframes move3 {
    0%   { width:0px;}
    100% { width:300px; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.5);}
}

@-moz-keyframes point {
    0%  {-moz-transform:scale(0,0);}
    100%{-moz-transform:scale(1,1);}    
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0%   {-moz-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0;}
    10%  {-moz-transform: scale(1);opacity: 0.5;}
    50%  {-moz-transform: scale(1.75);opacity: 0;}
    100% {-moz-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0;}  
} 

@-moz-keyframes tooltip {
    0%  { -moz-transform:scale(0,0); opacity:0;}
    50% { -moz-transform:scale(1.2,1.2); opacity:0.3; }
    75% { -moz-transform:scale(0.9,0.9); opacity:0.7;}
    100%{ -moz-transform:scale(1,1); opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0%   { width:0px;}
    100% { width:200px; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.5); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move1 {
    0%   { width:0px;}
    100% { width:200px; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.5); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move2 {
    0%   { width:0px;}
    100% { width:400px; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.5); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move3 {
    0%   { width:0px;}
    100% { width:300px; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,198,255,0.5); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes point {
    0%  {-webkit-transform:scale(0,0);}
    100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0%   {-webkit-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0;}
    10%  {-webkit-transform: scale(1);opacity: 0.5;}
    50%  {-webkit-transform: scale(1.75);opacity: 0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0;}  
} 

@-webkit-keyframes tooltip {
    0%  { -webkit-transform:scale(0,0); opacity:0;}
    50% { -webkit-transform:scale(1.2,1.2); opacity:0.3; }
    75% { -webkit-transform:scale(0.9,0.9); opacity:0.7;}
    100%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1,1); opacity:1;}
}

/* Trigger button for javascript */

.trigger {
    background: #000000;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #161616 0%, #000000 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #161616 0%,#000000 100%);
    border-left:1px solid #111; border-top:1px solid #111; border-right:1px solid #333; border-bottom:1px solid #333; 
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 140px;
}

.trigger:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #202020 0%, #161616 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #202020 0%, #161616 100%);
}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('.content').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+100) {
                $(this).addClass('running');

            }


        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class=" container content" style="border:2px solid red; border-right-style:none; border-top-style:none;">

        <div id="layerBall" class="ball">
            <a href="#"><small>100 Visit</small></a>
        </div>
        <div id="layerPulse" class="pulse"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>

        <div id="layerBall1" class="ball1">
            <a href="#"><small>300 Visits</small></a>
        </div>
        <div id="layerPulse1" class="pulse1"></div>
        <div class="line1"></div>

        <div id="layerBall2" class="ball2">
            <a href="#"><small>10 Visits</small></a>
        </div>
        <div id="layerPulse2" class="pulse2"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>`enter code here`

        <div id="layerBall3" class="ball3">
            <a href="#"><small>4251 Visits</small></a>
        </div>
        <div id="layerPulse3" class="pulse3"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>


            </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `media-query` for responsive

Comment: but how so it become to big

Comment: due to `height` and `width`

Comment: can you do it and send me and look  i want to write content on left and bootom border so its look like x and y axix pls help me following is my code